# How do I add a header directly after a navbar in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, header, nav

I am trying to add a simple text header after a navbar on the same line (the very top of the webpage) and I can't seem to figure a way to keep them on the same line.

Code Below
CSS:

```css
.navbar div {
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;}
.one {width: 40px;}
.two { width: 30px;}
.three { width: 25px;}
.navbar:hover div { width: 40px;}

.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
    align-items: center;
    color: gold;}
```

HTML:

```html
<div>
<nav class="dropdown">
    <ul>
    <li>
    <a href="index.html" target="_blank" class="navbar">
        <div class="one"></div>
        <div class="two"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
    </a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Socials</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<h1 class = "header">Sam Jenkins</h1>
</div>
```

I tried wrapping the header and navbar together with a div tag while having the navbar float left and the header float right.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to apply flexbox properties to the header itself when it should be applied to a parent container.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar div {
  height: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 7px 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.one {width: 40px}
.two {width: 30px}
.three {width: 25px}
.navbar:hover div {width: 40px}

.header {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html" target="_blank" class="navbar">
          <div class="one"></div>
          <div class="two"></div>
          <div class="three"></div>
        </a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Socials</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <h1 class="header">Sam Jenkins</h1>
</header>
```